# possible to check when a user joined facebook using the graph api?

Tags: api, facebook

i would like to know whether it is possible to find out when a user joined facebook. or how long they have been a member. Is this possible using the facebook graph API?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. But you can try to approximate based on his uid (old Facebook users have shorter uids).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe crawl through the wall to the beginning?